# Kafka streams foreign key join with one-many relations

Tags: apache-kafka, java-stream, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

There are two kafka topics

- **news**
- **images**

A message in **news** topic can have list of image Ids as follows

```
{ 

    "id": "news-1",
    "title": "Title news-1",
    "description": " description news-1",
    "author": " Author news-1",
    "imageIds": [
        "images-1",
        "images-2"
    ]
}
```

A message in **images** topic looks like below

```
{

    "id": "image-1",
    "url": "https://www.mypublication.co.uk/image-title-1.jpeg",
    "description": "title-1 description",
    "height": 400,
    "width": 450
}


{

     "id": "image-2",
     "url": "https://www.mypublication.co.uk/image-title-2.jpeg",
     "description": "title-2 description",
     "height": 400,
     "width": 450
 }
```

I'm trying to join both of these streams to populate a final news message enriched with all the image details.

I tried using **groupBy** and **aggregate** as below

```
 KTable<String, Image> images = builder.table(topics.getImagesTopic(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), imageSerde));
    KStream<String, News> news = builder.stream(topics.getNewsTopic(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), newsSerde));

KTable<String, NewsImages> newsImagesKTable = news.flatMapValues(newsArticle -> newsArticle.getImageIds())
      .map((newsId, imageId) -> new KeyValue<>(imageId, newsId)) // rekey not good !!?
      .join(images, (newsId, image) -> {
        return new ImageWrapper(newsId, image);
      }, Joined.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), imageSerde))
            .groupBy((imageId, imageWrapper) -> imageWrapper.getNewsId(), Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), imageWrapperSerde))
      .aggregate(NewsImages::new, (newsId, image, newsImages) -> {
        newsImages.setNewsId(newsId);
        newsImages.addImage(image);
        return newsImages;
      }, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(),newsImagesSerde));

newsImagesKTable.toStream().
      to(topics.getNewsImagesTopic());
```

But as expected above code aggregates all the images for the news

When author publishes news for the first time with two images it goes well and we can see the output below

```
 "news-1" :
     {
       "newsId":"news-1", 
"images":
    {"image-1":{"id":"image-1","url":"https://www.mypublication.co.uk/image-1.jpeg","description":"title-1 description","height":400,"width":450},
        "image-2":{"id":"image-2","url":"https://www.mypublication.co.uk/image-2.jpeg","description":"title-2 description","height":400,"width":450}}
                }
```

When author re-published the article with only image-3 currently it's outputting all three images (That's what aggregator is)
**news-1 : [image-1, image-2, image-3]**

I'm looking for any other alternative ways to join news & images and override the previous values on re-publishing the news
**news-1 : [image-3]**

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache Kafka 2.4, FK-joins is a native DSL operator: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-foreign-key-join

For more details checkout https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-foreign-key-join